# Statement execution in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure (simplified version) as below. In general it will push the pending items to email queue and update the status of those items to pushed. This stored procedure has been called in a 60 seconds interval.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateEmailQueue]
AS
BEGIN
    insert into EmailQueue
        select * 
        from actionstatus 
        where actionstatus='Pending'

    update actionstatus 
    set actionstatus = 'Pushed'
    where actionstatus = 'Pending' 
END
```

It works fine but I found one exception record. The exception's action status has been changed to "Pushed" but the record did not appear in the EmailQueue. I suspected that the action status record has been generated after the insert but before the update. But I am not 100% sure as I assume that SQL Server always execute a stored procedure in an isolation block so the data change won't affect the data set inside the execution. Could someone help explain the actual process inside the stored procedure, review this stored procedure and advise if it is OK, or it should be put in a transaction block? and, any performance or locking issue for doing this in transaction? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You must use transactins inside stored procedure. SQL Server don't generate transactions for stored procedures calls automatically. You can simply check it by execute code something like taht:

```
insert ...
--this will falls
select 1/0
```

Insertion will be done and than you'll have division by zero error